# How to solve this error "CoreText/CTParagraphStyle.h" file is not found?

Tags: iphone, ios6, xcode5, crash-reports, hockeyapp

I am new to iOS.
For find the crash reports I am using Hockey app.
I followed the same procedure  in the given site "http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration/hockeyapp-for-ios".
But i got that error.
Anybody can explain what is meaning of the following statement

"If you are already using a .xcconfig file, simply add the following line to it

## include "../Vendor/HockeySDK/Support/HockeySDK.xcconfig"

(Adjust the path depending where the Project.xcconfig file is located related to the Xcode project package)"

Please give me solution
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I bet you missed out this step, or didn't complete it properly:

10:

> If you are getting build warnings, then the .xcconfig setting wasn't included successfully or its settings in Other Linker Flags get
>   ignored because $(interited) is missing on project or target level.
>   Either add $(inherited) or link the following frameworks manually in
>   Link Binary With Libraries under Build Phases:
>
> CoreText
>
> CoreGraphics
>
> Foundation
>
> QuartzCore
>
> SystemConfiguration
>
> UIKit

Comment: @user2396621 Check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added CoreText to your frameworks?

```
Build Phases - Link Binary With Libraries
```

And look for CoreText library